# How to resize OpenLayers map before print

Tags: openlayers, printing, css

I have an OpenLayers map container defined as

```
#preview_cont {
    width: 100%;
    height: 15cm;
}
```

It looks OK on screen, but when I print it, the map is distorted. I assume it's because map container proportions are changed when printing. As far as I know, in such a case

```
ol.Map.updateSize()
```

has to be called. So I tried this function:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
        map.updateSize();
});
```

Unfortunately, it's not called for printing. Is there a way, how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The approach I use is to:

1. Adapt the size of the view with something like:

   ```
   var orgSize = map.getSize();
   var newSize = [newWidth, newHeight];
   map.setSize(newSize);
   map.getView().fit(extent, {size: newSize});
   ```
2. Start printing when the map is completly rerendered:

   ```
   map.once('rendercomplete', function(event) { 
       startPrint();
   ```
3. And finally render it again with the original size:

   ```
       map.setSize(orgSize);
       map.getView().fit(extent, {size: size});
   } );
   ```

Comment: I'm getting extent is not defined error, do you have any ideas ?

Comment: @Capan, you need to use your own extent. geraldo just gave you an example.